# Deriving forward looking features based on windows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with ids, dates and sales amount.

```
id  date    amount
1   2023-01-01  20
1   2023-01-02  0
1   2023-01-03  0
1   2023-01-04  10
1   2023-01-05  15
1   2023-01-06  0
1   2023-01-07  0
2   2023-02-13  25
2   2023-02-14  32
2   2023-02-15  0
2   2023-02-16  12
2   2023-02-17  0
2   2023-02-18  0
2   2023-02-19  0
2   2023-02-20  13
2   2023-02-21  0
2   2023-02-22  12
```

I want to create buckets of no-sales-days and create a dataframe like this. The consecutive_zero_count column counts the consecutive 0 sales amount days. The last 3 columns are the maximum number of consecutive_zero_count values between days 0-to-2, 3-to-5 and 6-to-9. The final data I want is below. I tried to create panel data but that approach is not scaling because I have more than 20M rows and each id can span as long as 5 years. Is there a way to achieve this? Any pointers would be helpful.

| id | date | amount | consec_zero_count | max_dnp_d0_d2 | max_dnp_d3_d5 | max_dnp_d6_d9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 20 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-04 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 2 | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | 15 | 0 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-06 | 0 | 1 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-07 | 0 | 2 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-13 | 25 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 2023-02-14 | 32 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-02-15 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-02-16 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-02-17 | 0 | 3 | 5 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-18 | 0 | 4 | 5 | 1 | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-19 | 0 | 5 | 5 | 0 | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-20 | 13 | 0 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-21 | 0 | 1 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-02-22 | 12 | 0 | 0 | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
g = df.groupby("id")

df["consec_zero_count"] = (
    g["amount"]
    .apply(
        lambda x: (x.groupby(((m := x.eq(0)) != m.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1) * m
    )
    .values
)

indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=3)
df["max_dnp_d0_d2"] = (
    g.rolling(indexer, min_periods=1)["consec_zero_count"].max().astype(int).values
)
df["max_dnp_d3_d5"] = g["max_dnp_d0_d2"].shift(-3)
df["max_dnp_d6_d9"] = g["max_dnp_d3_d5"].shift(-3)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id        date  amount  consec_zero_count  max_dnp_d0_d2  max_dnp_d3_d5  max_dnp_d6_d9
0    1  2023-01-01      20                  0              2            1.0            2.0
1    1  2023-01-02       0                  1              2            2.0            NaN
2    1  2023-01-03       0                  2              2            2.0            NaN
3    1  2023-01-04      10                  0              1            2.0            NaN
4    1  2023-01-05      15                  0              2            NaN            NaN
5    1  2023-01-06       0                  1              2            NaN            NaN
6    1  2023-01-07       0                  2              2            NaN            NaN
7    2  2023-02-13      25                  0              1            4.0            5.0
8    2  2023-02-14      32                  0              2            5.0            1.0
9    2  2023-02-15       0                  1              3            5.0            1.0
10   2  2023-02-16       0                  2              4            5.0            0.0
11   2  2023-02-17       0                  3              5            1.0            NaN
12   2  2023-02-18       0                  4              5            1.0            NaN
13   2  2023-02-19       0                  5              5            0.0            NaN
14   2  2023-02-20      13                  0              1            NaN            NaN
15   2  2023-02-21       0                  1              1            NaN            NaN
16   2  2023-02-22      12                  0              0            NaN            NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej for your response. In you code, `indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=3)`, how to have variable window size. for example, in some cases I want window size 3, 7 and 9 in the same code. How to modify this? Thanks.

Comment: @buntipapu If I understand you correctly, you can modify the `window_size=` parameter.